# Google OAuth for type TV and Limited Input

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to develop an app similar to Google Drive for my TV (Tizen OS).
For this I have created a project on Google Cloud.
In the project I have created OAuth2.0 credential for type **"TV and Limited Input device"**.
For above type, credential creator does not request to set any redirect url.
Nor it provides any default redirect url in the credential json file.

But when i am authenticating with end point `"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"` (Or)
`"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"` with scope `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

It throws below Error

> Error 400: invalid_request
> Missing required parameter: redirect_uri

I have used some random redirect url it throws me an error

> Authorisation Error
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

I used local host as redirect url but it gave me below error

> Authorisation Error
> Error 400: invalid_request
> Localhost URI is not allowed for 'NATIVE_DEVICE' client type.

I have tried authenticating with endpoint `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code`, but it does not work for `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. Rather it worked for `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. But drive.file scope does not satisfy my requirement, as I need to show all documents of the owner in the app.

Any one has an idea what is the redirect URL we need to use in case of Limited Input Device with a `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to get full access of drive api's ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation for [OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device)

You will see this at the top of the page.

[image]

You will find that it states [Allowed scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#allowedscopes)

[image]

Which means that you are not going to be able to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as its not supported